# Cast qualifier to "TrainEngine" meaning?

Tags: java, oop, multiple-inheritance

I am New to Java and OOPs Concepts, I am having trouble with this.

I have this function in the `Train` Class (it associates the `TrainCar` Class) in which I am running a for loop to loop through an array of Objects of type `TrainCar`. `TrainCar` is the parent class from which inherits the `AdminCar` Class, which is further inherited by the `TrainEngine` Class.

the `TrainEngine` Class has a getter getPower, `TrainCar` or `AdminCar` does not have that.

when I want to access that method IntelliJ recommends me to change `totalPower += car.getPower();` to `totalPower += ((TrainEngine) car).getPower();`. I don't know what this line means and does. I would really appreciate it If you guys could explain this.

```
 public double getMaxAccel() {
    double totalPower = 0;
    double totalWeight = 0;
    for (TrainCar car: trainCar) {
        totalWeight += car.getWeight();
        if (car instanceof TrainEngine) {
            totalPower += ((TrainEngine) car).getPower();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `car` is always a `TrainCar` (but you forgot to include the class and interface definitions in your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to increase the totalPower, the line `totalPower += ((TrainEngine) car).getPower();` is attempting to access the getPower method for each TrainCar object. However, the getPower method is only available in the TrainEngine class, not in the TrainCar class itself.

By using the type cast (TrainEngine) car, you are telling the compiler explicitly that you know the car object is of type TrainEngine. Therefore, it allows you to access the getPower() method without a compilation error.

Since you are new, I would advise you to study further into the **Polymorphism** and Inheritance concepts. I believe it will give you a good understanding of this problem.

I will give an example:

You have a class named Animal and two subclasses Cat and Dog. Let's say you have a `bark()` method in the Dog class and `meow()` method in the Cat class.

Say you want to create an instance of Dog from the parent class, Animal as follows:

`Animal yourDog = new Dog();`

Now you know that this object will be a dog but the computer doesn't. Hence, if you want to call the `bark()` method of the subclass Dog, you need to tell the compiler that this object should be treated as a Dog.

So, you do this when calling the bark() method:

`((Dog) animalDog).bark();`

Hope this helps, good luck on your journey buddy! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is called **(type) casting**.

From your description, I believe the `TrainEngine` class *extends* the `TrainCar` class and `getPower` method is present in the `TrainEngine` child class.

When you have a reference to a `TrainCar`, it could be any class which extends it. So by checking `car instanceof TrainEngine`, you are checking if the `TrainCar` reference is actually an instance of `TrainEngine` and if so you can **cast** the object which is stored as a `TrainCar` reference to a `TrainEngine`.

```
if (car instanceof TrainEngine) {
    TrainEngine trainEngine = (TrainEngine) car;
}
```

Note: You aren't creating a new object here. You are just accessing the same object as a `TrainEngine` (the child class).

Now using the *trainEngine* local variable, you can access all the methods on the `TrainEngine` class and hence you can access the `getPower` method.

```
if (car instanceof TrainEngine) {
    TrainEngine trainEngine = (TrainEngine) car;
    totalPower += trainEngine.getPower();
}
```

The suggestion from IDE is to combine the cast and calling the `getPower` method in one line.

```
totalPower += ((TrainEngine) car).getPower();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! now I get it, it's just weird syntax but typecasting at its core.